# Format AWS Transcribe Audio Identification

Tags: amazon-web-services, audio, formatting, amazon-transcribe

I've been searching for this solution, couldn't find anything reasonably to what AWS currently have on their UI, so came up with mine in laravel, and dropping it here to help anyone hopefully searching for this as well.

Answer (score 0):

```php
public function convertTextToSpeakers($response)
    {
        $segments = $response['results']['speaker_labels']['segments'];
        $items    = $response['results']['items'];
        $result   = [];

        foreach ($items as $key => $item) {

            if (!isset($item['start_time'])) {

                $prev_item = $items[$key - 1];

                if ($prev_item) {

                    $item['start_time'] = $prev_item['start_time'];
                    $item['end_time']   = $prev_item['end_time'];
                    $items[$key]        = $item;
                }
            }
        }

        foreach ($segments as $key => $segment) {

            $has_data = true;

            $temp_key = $key;

            while ($has_data) {

                $temp_key++;

                $next_segment = $segments[$temp_key] ?? null;

                if ($next_segment && $next_segment['speaker_label'] == $segment['speaker_label']) {

                    $itemsData = array_merge($segment['items'], $next_segment['items']);

                    $segment['items'] = $itemsData;

                    unset($segments[$temp_key]);

                    $segments[$key] = $segment;

                } else {

                    $has_data = false;
                }
            }

        }

        $items = collect($items);

        $segments = collect($segments)->sortBy('start_time');

        foreach ($segments as $segment) {

            $text = '';

            $segmentItems = collect($segment['items'])->sortBy('start_time');

            foreach ($segmentItems as $seg_item) {

                $words = $items->where('start_time', $seg_item['start_time'])
                    ->where('end_time', $seg_item['end_time']);

                foreach ($words as $word) {

                    $text .= $word['alternatives'][0]['content'];
                }

                $text .= " ";
            }

            $result[] = [
                'speaker' => $segment['speaker_label'],
                'text'    => $text,
            ];
        }

        return $result;
    }
```